# Como faço para saber qual o script manipulou um dom e modificou os atributos da HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, dom, console

É possível saber através do console?

> **Imagine essa história:** Você tenha vários arquivos de JavaScript embutidos na header da página, e quando você envia um post, do nada aparece um style="display:none" no input do retorno, porém não é do PHP que ele está fazendo isso, é de algum script em JavaScript ou jquery, ou dom, é possível localizar o elemento que o modificou, se você souber que ele usou o elemento, a classe ou id do input para capturá-lo e modificá-lo, tem algum lugar no console que você consegue saber qual o javascript que modificou isso, ou algum script que eu possa fazer para capturar o método que executou essa mudança, sei lá?

Comment: abre o dev tools, e debuga a página

Comment: falou grego agora. Onde fica o dev tools? Eu uso Chrome.

Comment: no seu google chrome, pressione a tecla F12, clique na aba sources, depois clique no botão que tem um ícone de um pause. atualiza a página ou manda o post e veja que ele vai ir parando em cada ponto onde o javascript é executado, vai aparecer umas abas abaixo com o script que ta executando aquele evento

Comment: Eu já havia tentado isso, mas não consegui localizar... por isso achei que havia outras formas, mas eu acabei usando o firefox, ele tem um debug melhor para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já encontrei a solução, abri o debug do Firefox e consegui ver os arquivos que são carregados durante a execução.